# Modeller 9.14 "ValueError: Too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, terminal

I'm using a protein structure modelling tool called "Modeller" that's based on Python and I keep getting this error

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

When I try to run the following script:

```
from modeller import *

env = environ()
aln = alignment(env)
for (pdb, chain) in (('tseq1', 'A')):
    m = model(env, file=pdb, model_segment=('FIRST:'+chain, 'LAST:'+chain))
    aln.append_model(m, atom_files=pdb, align_codes=pdb+chain)
aln.malign()
aln.malign3d()
aln.compare_structures()
aln.id_table(matrix_file='family.mat')
env.dendrogram(matrix_file='family.mat', cluster_cut=-1.0)
```

I've tried changing 'tseq1' (template sequence), just in case I got the wrong file and it's supposed to be qseq1, which is my query sequence. But it doesn't make a difference and I keep getting the same error. I read somewhere that this error occurs when I try to unpack too many values into an object that's not got enough variables to unpack them to, but I can't see where 'tseq1' is going in this script. 
When I run this code in terminal I use the following command (just in case that has something to do with it, which I doubt):

```
mod9.14 script2.py
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: First, put the complete error message in your question...
Also add which version of python you are using.

Comment: post the complete error message along.

Comment: to me, the problem lies in the tuple you are extracting in the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error must be in this line:

```
for (pdb, chain) in (('tseq1', 'A')):
```

You are trying to unpack `tseq1` into two variables `pdb` and `chain`. Since Python strings are iterable, what happens is that `pdb` gets the `'t'` and `chain` the 's', but the interpreter does not know where to unpack the rest of the sequence (therefore the `too many values to unpack`).

What may be confusing you is that `(('tseq1', 'A'))` is pretty much the same as `('tseq1', 'A')`, i.e. it is not a sequence of tuples, it is just a 2-element tuple.

If you change the outer brackets to square brackets, you are converting the tuple into a list with only one tuple, and your code should not fail. (alternatively you can add a comma after the tuple to create a tuple of tuples `(('tseq1', 'A'), )`). However, I can't know if this is what you expect it to do:

```
for (pdb, chain) in [('tseq1', 'A')]:
```

By the way, the brackets for the unpacking are not necessary. This is the same:

```
for pdb, chain in [('tseq1', 'A')]:
```

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted the prev answer, but as an alternative you might want to add a comma to make the tuple work, if that is what you expect your code to do:

```
for (pdb, chain) in (('tseq1', 'A'),):
    print pdb, chain
```

produces:

```
tseq1 A
```

Answer (score 0):

try to this.

```
inv_type = (('tseq1', 'A'))
pdb, chain = inv_type if isinstance(inv_type, tuple) else [inv_type]
print pdb, chain
```